# Function Doubles() Python request an assistant

Tags: python, function

Hello first time asking a question on this forum.

I'm having trouble with this question.

write a function`doubles()` that takes as input a list of integers and outputs the integers in the list that are exactly twice that previous integer in the list, one per line.

So what I've been trying to do at first was to write a code that goes through the list of integers by using index

Such as:

```
integers = []

def doubles(integers):
    index = 0
    while index < len(integers):
        if index == (2*(index+1)):           
            print(index)

doubles([3,0,1,2,3,6,2,4,5,6,5])
```

What I think of the code I've written is that. While the index is less than the length of the list of integers, if the index is equal to double the next index it will print out that number. However I've seem to not get the result I want. Thank you.

Comment: What should `doubles([3,0,1,2,3,6,2,4,5,6,5])` output? Your definition isn't exactly clear to me.

Comment: erm... you are never looking up the values of the list. You are simply comparing the indices. somewhere you must access `integers[index]` to obtain such values. Also, if you never increment `index` you have an infinite loop. Finally, in python you want to avoid that kind of loop as much as you can. Iterating by index is *much* slower than iterating over the list directly and, also, produces worse code readability-wise.

Comment: your question and your code are not about the same thing. Try to express better what you need

Comment: So you call the function doubles([3......5]). Right then what the code should do is go through the list of integers. If the integer is double the previous integer then it should print out that integer.

For instance. in the list of 3,0,1,2,3,6,2,4,5,6,5:

2 is the double of 1 so it'll print out 2, 6 is double of 3, so it'll print out 6. 4 is double 2, so itll print out 2

Answer (score 2):

You are are doing a couple things that need fixed.

1. You want to be looking at the items in the list `integers` instead of the indexes of those items. You do this by looking at `integers[n]` where n is the index.
2. You want to be comparing to the previous value from the list, not the next one, so you should be comparing `integers[index]` to `integers[index-1]` as opposed to a notation with `index + 1`
3. You should be looping through the list of indices. Your `while` loop will never terminate in this example. You could do a `while index < len(integers)` then increment index up by one each time, but it is easier to do a for loop.

Try this:

```
def doubles(integers):
    index = 0
    for index in range(1,len(integers)):
        if integers[index] == 2*integers[index-1]:           
            print(integers[index])
```

Comment: Thank you that helped alot.

I see that for index in range 1 to the length of intgers; if integer[i] is double the intger[i-1] (which means the previous integer) it'll print out integer[i] Okay thank you. 

Reading code is not hard but writing code is hard for me haha. Once again thank you

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as answered by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
>>> def doubles(integers):
...  return [j for i,j in zip(integers,integers[1:]) if j==2*i]
... 
>>> doubles([3,0,1,2,3,6,2,4,5,6,5])
[2, 6, 4]
```

with `zip(integers,integers[1:]` you can earn all pair of tandem indices.

```
[(3, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 6), (6, 2), (2, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 5)]
```

Comment: It is asking for """the integers in the list that are exactly twice that previous integer in the list, one per line""", so you would want `return [j for i,j in zip(integers,integers[1:]) if j==2*i]`, but otherwise this a nice way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
doubles = lambda l: reduce(lambda x,y: (print(y) or y) if 2*x==y else y, l) or None
```

That should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :-

```
(j for i, j in enumerate(integers) if integers[i] == 2*integers[i-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def doubles(integers):
    index = 0
    for index in range(1,len(integers)):
        if integers[index] == 2*integers[index-1]:           
            print(integers[index])
def doubles(integers):
    index = 0
    for index in range(1,len(integers)):
        if integers[index] == 2*integers[index-1]:           
            print(integers[index])
def doubles(integers):
    index = 0
    for index in range(1,len(integers)):
        if integers[index] == 2*integers[index-1]:           
            print(integers[index])
def doubles(integers):
    index = 0
    for index in range(1,len(integers)):
        if integers[index] == 2*integers[index-1]:           
            print(integers[index])
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not encouraged on SO, as they do not explain how the code works. Please add an explanation to help the OP and others learn.

Comment: ... and edit the formatting of your answer. code should be fomatted as code.